# Can I use a NSData file from OS X in iOS

Tags: ios, macos, serialization, nsdata

I have a level editor for my iOS App and it's running on OS X. It saves the levels in an archived `NSData`-Object. These files are inside my apps bundle and I try to load them on the iOS app using:

```
NSString* path_ = [dictionary_ objectForKey:kWDLevelController_Level_PathKey];
NSString* sourcePath_ = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path_ ofType:@"wds"];

NSData* data_ = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sourcePath_ 
                                       options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];
dataSource_ = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data_];
```

The returned `NSData` object is empty. I checked the path of the `NSData`-File inside the bundle and it's correct. I guess that it's the problem that the file was created on OS X and that I want to deserialize it on iOS.

Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to write my own serialization class or use any third-party?

Comment: Are you sure the files made it in to the bundle?  Make sure the target membership for your data files is checked on.  You might want to add fileExists check to make sure it can even read the file

BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:sourcePath_];

Comment: @jaybers file is in bundle. If not I get an error saying file not found.

Comment: @Wain error is empty!